# Use GROUP BY values as columns with COUNT over time

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to count the different types of emails (`template`) my system has sent per day.  I can get these values with:

```
select to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD') period,
    count(*) num,
    template
from email_log
group by period, template
order by period desc, template
```

My results look like

```
period     | num  | template
-----------+------+---------
2021-12-09 | 185  | reminder
2021-12-09 | 80   | thankyou
2021-12-09 | 1224 | welcome
2021-12-08 | 327  | reminder
2021-12-08 | 108  | thankyou
2021-12-08 | 1698 | welcome
```

However because of the multiple `group by`s I'm getting more than one row per day.  How can I extrapolate the `template` value into columns, with the `count(*)` as the cell value?  Meaning my columns are the template names, my rows are the counts.  For example, it would look like

```
period     | reminder | thankyou | welcome
-----------+----------+----------+--------
2021-12-09 | 185      | 80       | 1224
2021-12-08 | 327      | 108      | 1698
```

Is this possible to do in plain SQL, and efficiently?  Otherwise I need to use another program to take these values as a CSV and restructure the data.

Bonus bonus points if I can add a sum of all the columns at the end as a `total`

---

The closest I've been able to get is this, but it requires me to hardcode the template values and it's not very efficient

```
select to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD') period,
    sum(case when template = 'reminder' then 1 else 0 end) as reminder,
    sum(case when template = 'thankyou' then 1 else 0 end) as thankyou,
    sum(case when template = 'welcome' then 1 else 0 end) as welcome,
    count(*) total
from email_log
group by period
order by period desc
```

Comment: That's a pivot/crosstab table, but you need to know the column names in advance. You can use `select ... from crosstab(...) as (period date, reminder integer, thankyou integer, welcome integer, ...)`

Comment: This is much easier done in your frontend when you _display_ the data. One approach to make it easier in the frontend might be be to aggregate the data into JSON key/value pairs. Then you don't need to know the column names in advance.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Do you want to expand your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

First you can replace

```
sum(case when template = 'reminder' then 1 else 0 end)
```

by

```
count(*) filter (where template = 'reminder')
```

which may be a bit faster.

Then here is a (not-straight-forward) solution where the column names and number are not known before the run time :

**First step :** create a composite type `email_templates` which corresponds to the list of the columns as expected :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE email_templates ()
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE
  composite_type_list text ;
BEGIN
  SELECT '(period date,' || string_agg(DISTINCT template || ' integer', ',') || ',total integer)'
    INTO composite_type_list 
    FROM email_log ;

  EXECUTE 'DROP TYPE IF EXISTS email_templates' ;
  EXECUTE 'CREATE TYPE email_templates AS ' || composite_type_list ;
END ;
$$ ;

CALL email_templates () ;
```

**Second step :** create the plpgsql function `daily_synthesis()` with a dynamic query structured according to the new composite type `email_templates`, and returning a set of `json` :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION daily_synthesis ()
RETURNS setof json LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE
  columns_list text ;
BEGIN
  SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT 'count(*) filter (where template = ' || quote_nullable(template) || ')', ',')
    INTO columns_list 
    FROM email_log ;

  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
  E'select row_to_json(row(to_char(created_at, \'YYYY-MM-DD\'), ' || columns_list || ', count(*)) :: email_templates)
     from email_log
    group by created_at
    order by created_at desc' ;
END ;
$$ ;
```

**Third step :** call the function `daily_synthesis()` and convert the json result into a record with the expected columns :

```
select b.* 
  from daily_synthesis () as a
 cross join lateral json_populate_record (null :: email_templates, a) as b
```

result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d20870cfb41268d6f17e11bb42661c6e) :

```
period      reminder    thankyou    welcome     total
2021-12-09  2           2           2           6
```

Comment: I would probably just create a VIEW (dynamically) rather than going through the steps using a type

Comment: Good point ! thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Do it client side, or with the query you already have.

There is the crosstab function in [tablefunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html), but it is pretty gross and I don't think it has any advantages over what you already have.

If you want a total row as well as a total column, you could change the `group by period` to `group by rollup (period)`